# swapping characters in a file

Tags: file, character, swap

I have been trying to swap characters in a txt file. In class we are doing a maze and i have the basics down of how to swap characters in array. For example the maze looks like this _________ and i have to swap the $ with a
                                |$
space. this is what I have so far(in function form). I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use a file in my code

```
void SwapTwo(char p[], char q[], int x, int y)
{
  char p="$"
  char q=" "
    char temp = p[x];
    p[x] = q[y];
    q[y] = temp;
}
int main()
    char filename[1024];
    char array[23][79];

    printf("\nEnter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    SwapTwo(array[p], array[q], x, y);

    fclose(file);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: my question is how do you swap characters in a file, i'm having a hard time trying to see that, and there isnt much online for examples

Comment: my maze looks like this, i have to swap the $ with the space
|$
 ________